# custom function to dynamically return database value in php

Tags: php

```
<?php
function  createDBQuery($tableName, $condition, $cvalue,$pos) {
include('../connect.php');

$sqlStatement="select * from  $table where $condition = $cvalue";

$result = $db->prepare($sqlStatement);

$result= $result->execute(); 

for($i=0; $rowTable = $result->fetch(); $i++){


    if($rowTable)
    {
        echo $rowTable[$pos];
    }
    else
    {
        echo $rowTable[0];
    }


}
```

}

**Body**

```
$cval=$row['fileID'];
$file= createDBQuery('file','fileID',$cval,'1');
//print_r($file); 
echo $file;
```

**Output**

> Call to a member function fetch() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\pos\main\purchase.php:88

Comment: Is your `$table` in your query is the `$tableName` of your function ?

Comment: replace $result->fetch() with $result->fetch_array()

Comment: Your function does not [`return`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) anything, the error message makes your question a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/2973202/4265352, there is no variable called `$table` (it is `$tableName` in the function's parameters list).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using [mysqli_stmt::execute](https://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) (or similar) and `$result->execute()` obviously returns a boolean. Aou assign it to `$result` and then try to call `fetch()` on a boolean.

Just replace `$result= $result->execute();` with `$result->execute();`